# Unable to display view when I call it from a separate ViewController in iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I have a view controller in my application where on my screen I have a UIView that the user is required to tap on.  When they do that, I want to call another viewController's view, and display it on the screen for the user.  Unfortunately, I am having trouble displaying the view.

The name of my viewController that I am making the call from is called "MainViewController", and the ViewController whose view I wish to display is called, "NextViewController"

Here is my code from where I make the call:

```
- (void) touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    
    NSLog(@"I was touched.");
    
    _nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] init]; //this code is not being called
    [self.view addSubview:_nextView.view];         //neither is this being called
    
}
```

Where _nextView is a property that I declare in the .h file of MainViewController.

This method is being called, but for some reason because I am able to see the log statements print to the output, but for some reason I am unable to call the lines after that.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to segue to nextViewController, not only alloc init. In most case you push a viewController into a NavigationController stack. Try to learn it from here: http://simplecode.me/2011/09/04/an-introduction-to-uinavigationcontroller/

Comment: Thanks very much for your prompt reply.  Do I really need to do this if all I want to do is simply display a view that requires the user to enter some data, and then return back to the original screen?  Do I even need a viewController at all to be called in order to display the view, or can I simply call the view itself, and once the user is finished with the view, dismiss the view, and return back to the main screen?

Comment: In that case you don't really need another ViewController (you can if you like, depends on your UI flow design). You can alloc init a UITextView or UITextField, and add it as subview of self.view, to collect user input. A tutorial for UITextField (http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/ios-app-builder/how-to-collect-text-input-using-uitextfield/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't add the view of another view controller to your view without making that view controller a child view controller. If you just want a view, then set one up in a xib file and add it to your view as a subview. If you want to use a view controller, then you should present it modally, and dismiss it when you're done. This kind of situation where you want to gather some info from the user to use in your app, is an appropriate place to use a modal view controller. MainViewController should set itself as the delegate of NextViewController, and NextViewController should define a delegate protocol to send the data back to MainViewController.

To present it modally, do this:

```
_nextView = [[NextViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"your nib name here" bundle:nil];
[self presentViewController:_nextView animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: I think you've hit the nail here.  This is what I would like to do, but not sure how.  I have created the view from inside the .xib file of the viewController.  You're saying I should present it modally.  How would I do this?  Can you give me an example, if possible?

Comment: @syedfa, I've updated my post. You really should read the "View Controller Programming Guide for iOS", it explains a lot about how to use view controllers.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Navigation Controller? Or Storyboards? One way of displaying another view controller would be like this:

```
[self presentViewController:_nextView animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

A couple of things:
 - If your NSLog gets called, then so do the other two lines you say do not.
 - I assume you mean you want to display the other **view controller** on screen, not display the other view controller's **view** on the first view controller. These are two very different things, the second of which you wouldn't want to do.

Comment: I'm actually using storyboards, but I created the view for my NextViewController in its .xib file.  In answer to your second question, I actually do want to display the other viewController's view on the first viewController (not within, but over top of, which would then be dismissed by the user when they are done, and returned back to the MainViewController).  This unfortunately is indeed what I want to do, and if I am going about it incorrectly, how should I do it?

Comment: I should have been more clear with what I meant; what the code in your question is trying to do is add the secondViewController's view (a UIView object, not a UIViewController) as a subview of the firstViewController's view (UIView). This is very different from having one viewController present/segue to another viewController. I also should have said that to present the view controller using the code in my answer you will need in initialise the viewController using initWithNibName:bundle:, as per rdelmar's answer.